# Salvaging the Wikipedia Proof of Chow's Lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I've got most of a proof of Chow's Lemma worked out following the sketch in Hartshorne. I wanted to compare notes with what was on the internet and was pleased to see wikipedia had a proof of this fact.

Unfortunately, at the end, the proof gets pretty bizarre. There are a handful of maps that don't appear to be defined anywhere else, and the last argument appears to be a diagram chase with no diagram. I've tried to reconstruct this diagram myself just from seeing the apparent commutativtity relations, but I appear to have twisted myself up in knots.

Can anyone help me straighten out the end of the proof here? [Here's a link to the page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%27s_lemma#Proof)

Comment: You may wish to compare with the Stacks project proof: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O2